# Can't get function to work on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var lastElement = false;
    $("ul li").each(function() {
        if (!lastElement || lastElement.offset().top == $(this).offset().top) {
            // add slash
            $(lastElement).after(' /');
        }
        lastElement = $(this);
    })
});
```

Basically it will add slashs after every li element, with the exception that if the li is the last in the line it will not add slash. I tried to use this same function to resize, but when the window is resized, it adds several slashs without removing the other.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2ULx/23/

Any idea?
Thanks...

Comment: you should write the resize code

Comment: I was just trying to do with css, but the last few elements of each row there is a bar without some nexus ...

Comment: Resize is called like every few MS during the resize and not just when it's complete. And you don't write any code to remove the slashes, so why would you expect it to remove them?

Comment: it will be a responsive menu, and became stranger a lost slash at the end of each line...

Comment: You should really cache `$(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the content directly

you can try to control the class

for example:

```
$(lastElement).addClass('hasSlash');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2ULx/25/

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer of Ian Wang (and referring to your comment):

You can, of course, use pure CSS for doing this job:

```
li:not(:last-of-type):after{
    content:" / ";
}
```

The problem(?) is that you will have to remove the unwanted slashes manually using media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    li:nth-of-type(3n):after {
        content:"";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's better to use JavaScript or CSS. I think I'd prefer the CSS solution.

Comment: but this CSS code will work every 3 elements is not? I need something dynamic ...

Comment: It's just an example. You would have to define more than this single breakpoint to make it work correctly. But since you seem to build a responsive layout, it may not be a real problem after all.